# Sorting by Votes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `Responses` and a table `Votes`.  The `Votes` table has a column `vote_value` which can either be `1` or `-1` depending on whether people vote up or down on a given response.  I'm wondering how I can sort responses by the sum of the votes on them.

The problem with doing a join and simply ordering by `SUM(vote.vote_value) as score` (descending) is that some responses don't have votes, so a response with a `score` of -1 will be higher up than a response with no votes on it (which would be a score of 0 really).

If there's no way to do this with SQL, I suppose I could just do the sorting myself in the application code.

Comment: Can you please post the query you are using? I am pretty sure you are missing something very easy. (my guess would be a left join or sum returning null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [COALESCE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) to select a value when SUM returns NULL:

```
COALESCE(SUM(vote.vote_value), 0) AS score
```